# Finding the constant k given pdf of a random variable

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables, variance

The probability density function of a random variable W is given by:

$$f(w) = kw^4e^w$$

for $2.002\leq w\leq 3.543$

a. Find constant $k$

b. Compute for $E(W)$

c. Compute for $Var(W)$

d. What is the probability that W will have a value greater than 2.5?

I have answered letter (a) for this no. however I'm not sure if I got the right answer for it that's why I havent answered the next letters. I used integration by parts to integrate the fxn and equated it to 1 since one of the theorems for continuous pdf's states that the integral of the fxn should be equal to 1. I got k = 4.074487547x10^-4 and the integral is $e^w(w^4-4w^3+12w^2-24w+24)$. Did I get the correct answer? If not, please indicate why I got it wrong. Also, should I use the substitution rule for indefinite integrals for letter (d)? Thanks!

Comment: [Please read how to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Sorry! The image must not have loaded. I'll fix it. @AndrewTawfeek

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek here you go.

Comment: @AnnieCarmeliAntonio I've improved the formatting - please use LaTeX for writing equations in the future. Here's a handy [reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @Gokul yes, you are correct

Comment: Your integral seems correct. For $E(W)$, use $ \mu = \int x f(x) dx$ and for $Var(X)$, use $\int (x-\mu)^2 \cdot f(x) dx$.

Comment: For (d), your answer should be $\int_{2.5}^{3.543}f(w)dw$.

Comment: @Gokul okay, noted, for (d) do you say that because of 2.002 ≤ w ≤3.543?

Comment: @AnnieCarmeliAntonio Yes, because your pdf is defined between $2.002$ and $3.543$.